# Input field that dynamically monitors model value

Tags: object-oriented, design-patterns, mvc, actionscript-3

This question is regarding my approach to the following implementation requirement. Can you suggest a better alternative that doesn't suffer from the issues I'll point out in my implementation?

### REQUIREMENT:

Create an input field (View) that updates itself automatically whenever a specific property on the Model changes.

- The input field should be generic (ie: it should work for any Model, and any appropriately typed property)
- The Parent View that holds the Field should not be responsible for updating the field when the Model changes
- The programming language is ActionScript, which is a strongly typed EMCAScript variant. I'm not sure whether this is relevant, since this question doesn't deal with code directly.

### MY SOLUTION:

Model implements an Interface that defines the following methods:

- `registerInput()`: the Field registers itself with the model and indicates which properties it wants to monitor
- `unregisterInput()`: for cleanup /gc purposes
- `updateInputField()`: the Field can update the model when the user interacts with it

Input Field implements an Interface that defines the following method:

- `updateField()`: the Model can call this on any registered Field, when a monitored property changes

The Input Field is instantiated by the Parent View (that has a reference to the Model), by providing it with the Model instance (typed to the Interface) and the NAME (String) of the property on the Model we're want to monitor.

### ISSUES:

This solution works well, but there are two issues, both dealing with the fact that the Model's property is passed *as a string*, which means the IDE can't use autosuggest or type checking.

1. The Parent View passes the Model property **as a string**. So if there's a typo, we'll only find out about it at runtime, and we have to copy-and-paste it from the Model's function definition.
2. The Model updates the Field by passing the property **as a string**, with similar drawbacks.
3. The value of the property can't be typed for the IDE.

### Code:

#### ILiveModel

```
public interface ILiveModel 
{
    function registerLiveListener(liveListener:ILiveListener, fields:Array):Array;
    function unregisterLiveListener(liveListener:ILiveListener):void ;
    function updateLiveField(fieldName:String, newValue:*):void;
    function getLiveFieldValue(fieldName:String):*;
}
```

#### ILiveListener

```
public interface ILiveListener 
{
    function updateLiveField(field:String, value:*):void;
}
```

#### ILiveModel implementation

```
public class KioskModel extends EventDispatcher implements ILiveModel {
    private var _termsAndConditionsAgree:Boolean = false;
    protected var _liveListeners:Dictionary = new Dictionary(true);
    protected var _monitoredFields:Object = { };

    public function get termsAndConditionsAgree():Boolean {
        return _termsAndConditionsAgree;
    }

    public function set termsAndConditionsAgree(agree:Boolean):void {
        _termsAndConditionsAgree = agree;

        updateRegisteredLiveListeners("termsAndConditionsAgree");
    }

    public function registerLiveListener(liveListener:ILiveListener, fields:Array):Array {
        var monitoredFieldListeners:Array;
        var fieldValues:Array = [];

        trace("<o> Registering ", liveListener, " to watch ", fields);

        // Register the input in the Dictionary, so we can unregister its fields when asked to
        _liveListeners[liveListener] = fields;

        // For each field we've been asked to monitor, add the input, unless it's already watching that field
        for each(var field:String in fields) {
            if (! field in this) {
                throw new ArgumentError("Cannot register Listener Field '" + field + "' on model " + this + ": property or method does not exist");
            }
            monitoredFieldListeners = _monitoredFields[field];

            if (monitoredFieldListeners && monitoredFieldListeners.length) {
                if (monitoredFieldListeners.indexOf(liveListener == -1)) {
                    monitoredFieldListeners.push(liveListener);
                    _monitoredFields[field] = monitoredFieldListeners;
                }
            } else {
                _monitoredFields[field] = [liveListener];
            }

            fieldValues.push(getLiveFieldValue(field));
        }

        // Return an array of all the values we're watching, for convenience.
        return fieldValues;
    }

    public function unregisterLiveListener(liveListener:ILiveListener):void {
        var monitoredFields:Array = _liveListeners[liveListener];
        var monitoredFieldListeners:Array;
        var fieldIndex:int;

        trace("<-> Unregistering ", liveListener);

        if (monitoredFields) {
            for each (var field:String in monitoredFields) {
                monitoredFieldListeners = _monitoredFields[field];

                if (monitoredFieldListeners && monitoredFieldListeners.length) {
                    fieldIndex = monitoredFieldListeners.indexOf(liveListener);

                    if (fieldIndex != -1) {
                        monitoredFieldListeners.splice(fieldIndex, 1);

                        if (monitoredFieldListeners.length){
                            _monitoredFields[field] = monitoredFieldListeners;
                        } else {
                            delete _monitoredFields[field];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        delete _liveListeners[liveListener];
    }

    public function updateLiveField(fieldName:String, newValue:*):void {
        if (fieldName in this) {
            this[fieldName] = newValue;
        } else {
            throw new ArgumentError("Cannot update Listener Field '" + fieldName + "' on model " + this + ": property or method is not valid.");
        }
    }

    public function getLiveFieldValue(fieldName:String):* {
        if (fieldName in this) {
            return (this[fieldName]);
        } else {
            throw new ArgumentError("Listener Field '" + fieldName + "' in " + this + " is not a valid property or method");
        }
    }

    protected function updateRegisteredLiveListeners(fieldName:String) {            
        var liveListeners:Array = _monitoredFields[fieldName];

        if (liveListeners) {
            for each (var liveListener:ILiveListener in liveListeners) {
                liveListener.updateLiveField(fieldName, this[fieldName]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### ILiveListener implementation

```
public class InputRadioButtonView extends AssetView implements ILiveListener {
    private const LABEL_OFF = 'off';
    private const LABEL_ON = 'on';

    protected var _model:ILiveModel;
    protected var _modelProperty:String;
    protected var _value:Boolean;

    public function InputRadioButtonView(assetClip:*, model:ILiveModel, modelProperty:String, disabled:Boolean=false, localizableTextFieldName:String="label") {
        super(assetClip, disabled, localizableTextFieldName);

        _model = model;
        _modelProperty = modelProperty;
    }

    public function updateLiveField(field:String, value:*):void {
        updateClip();
    }


    /**
     * Be sure the clip accurately reflects the current value, every time we switch to its screen.
     */
    override public function setupBeforeLocalize():void {
        updateClip();

        super.setupBeforeLocalize();
    }

    override public function activate() {
        var values:Array;

        if (activatable) {
            clip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick, false, 0, true);
            values = _model.registerLiveListener(this, [_modelProperty]);

            DebugUtils.print_r(values);
        }

        super.activate();
    }

    override public function deactivate() {
        if (deactivatable) {
            clip.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
            _model.unregisterLiveListener(this);
        }

        super.deactivate();
    }

    /**
     * Attempts to update the clip, and lets you know if it was successful or not.
     * @return
     */
    protected function updateClip():Boolean {
        // Stash the value for convenience
        _value = _model.getLiveFieldValue(_modelProperty);

        if (clip){
            if (_value) {
                movieClip.gotoAndStop(LABEL_ON);
            } else {
                movieClip.gotoAndStop(LABEL_OFF);
            }

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    protected function onClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
        _model.updateLiveField(_modelProperty, ! _value);
    }
}
```

#### Parent View implementation

```
public class HowThisWorksBox extends ContentAssetView {
    private var _kioskModel:KioskModel;

    public function HowThisWorksBox(clip:*, disabled:Boolean = false) {
        super(clip, ["heading", "body"], disabled);
    }

    override protected function defineFlexItems(parentItem:FlexItem = null):FlexItem {
        _kioskModel = KioskModel.getInstance();

        return super.defineFlexItems(parentItem)
            .chainAsset(new ButtonAssetView("terms_button", ["label"], onTermsButtonClicked))
            .chainAsset(new InputRadioButtonView("agree_button", _kioskModel, "termsAndConditionsAgree"));
    }


    private function onTermsButtonClicked():void {
        screen.router.setScreen("main__terms");
    }
}
```

Leverages the [Kestrel](https://github.com/TomAuger/kestrel) mobile development framework - which defines the superclasses of this View.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: Absolutly no knowledge about actionscript.

---

InputRadioButtonView

> ```
> protected function updateClip():Boolean {
>     // Stash the value for convenience
>     _value = _model.getLiveFieldValue(_modelProperty);
>
>     if (clip){
>         if (_value) {
>             movieClip.gotoAndStop(LABEL_ON);
>         } else {
>             movieClip.gotoAndStop(LABEL_OFF);
>         }
>
>         return true;
>     }
>
>     return false;
> }
> ```

If I see a construct like this, the little guy in my head screems **USE A GUARD CLAUSE** to safe vertical spacing.

Another voice will ask me "Why is this `_value` variable filled if `clip != true`?"

The next one just states, "I can't read the code that easy because there aren't always spaces before a brace `{`.

So fixing these three points to silence the voices in my head is pretty straightforward like so

```
protected function updateClip():Boolean {

    if (!clip) {
        return false;
    }

    // Stash the value for convenience
    _value = _model.getLiveFieldValue(_modelProperty);

    if (_value) {
        movieClip.gotoAndStop(LABEL_ON);
    } else {
        movieClip.gotoAndStop(LABEL_OFF);
    }

    return true;

}
```

---

KioskModel

> ```
> public function unregisterLiveListener(liveListener:ILiveListener):void {
>     var monitoredFields:Array = _liveListeners[liveListener];
>     var monitoredFieldListeners:Array;
>     var fieldIndex:int;
>
>     trace("<-> Unregistering ", liveListener);
>
>     if (monitoredFields) {
>         for each (var field:String in monitoredFields) {
>             monitoredFieldListeners = _monitoredFields[field];
>
>             if (monitoredFieldListeners && monitoredFieldListeners.length) {
>                 fieldIndex = monitoredFieldListeners.indexOf(liveListener);
>
>                 if (fieldIndex != -1) {
>                     monitoredFieldListeners.splice(fieldIndex, 1);
>
>                     if (monitoredFieldListeners.length){
>                         _monitoredFields[field] = monitoredFieldListeners;
>                     } else {
>                         delete _monitoredFields[field];
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
>
>     delete _liveListeners[liveListener];
> }
> ```

This almost looks like a example of the [arrow code antipattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ArrowAntiPattern) which could be avoided by using a guard clause and `continue;` like so

```
public function unregisterLiveListener(liveListener:ILiveListener):void {
    var monitoredFields:Array = _liveListeners[liveListener];
    var monitoredFieldListeners:Array;
    var fieldIndex:int;

    trace("<-> Unregistering ", liveListener);

    if(!monitoredFields) {
        delete _liveListeners[liveListener];
        return; // don't know if this is possible in action script
    }

    for each (var field:String in monitoredFields) {
        monitoredFieldListeners = _monitoredFields[field];

        if (!(monitoredFieldListeners && monitoredFieldListeners.length)) {
            continue;
        }

        fieldIndex = monitoredFieldListeners.indexOf(liveListener);

        if (fieldIndex != -1) {
            monitoredFieldListeners.splice(fieldIndex, 1);

            if (monitoredFieldListeners.length){
                _monitoredFields[field] = monitoredFieldListeners;
            } else {
                delete _monitoredFields[field];
            }
        }
    }

    delete _liveListeners[liveListener];

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the good advice: I learned a few things here!